# how to check first field filled then only allow next field in android

Tags: java, android

In my app, i have one spinner and two autocompletetextview. If i select value from spinner then only allow to type first autocompletetextview, If some value in first autocompletetextview then only allow to type second autocompletetextview. 
How to do that.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        autocompletetextview.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
```

Please anyone help me!
Thanks in advance...

Comment: you can enable autocompletetextview only after spinner item select '

Comment: you can use enable method to do it. second.setEnabled(true/false);

Comment: I do like that.. But if i enable only after spinner item select means, autocompletetextview can't allow to type anything

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
autocompletetextview.setEnable(false);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        autocompletetextview.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        autocompletetextview.setEnable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        autocompletetextview.setEnable(false);
    }
});
autocompletetextview.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                autocompletetextview2.setEnable(s.toString().trim().length() > 0 ? true : false);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: why you disable spinner

Comment: User can't access widget when disabled.

Comment: Did you understand my question... I have only one spinner, why you use two spinner in your code

Comment: @hikoo sorry for some miss communication. I will look into question again and get back to you.

Comment: @hikoo I made few changes to my answer. Check and let me know if it works.